# How to get value of checked checkbox via jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get value of selected checkbox in my ajax form on onclick event.
The problem is that nothing is working and I cant get that value

```
<td>
<input type="checkbox" value="30" name="checkbox15" id="checkbox2" class="css-checkbox"><label for="checkbox2" class="css-label radGroup label_border css-checkbox_cl clr"> test</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="23" name="checkbox15" id="checkbox3" class="css-checkbox"><label for="checkbox3" class="css-label radGroup label_border css-checkbox_cl clr"> test2</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="15" name="checkbox15" id="checkbox4" class="css-checkbox"><label for="checkbox4" class="css-label radGroup label_border css-checkbox_cl clr"> test3</label>
</td>
```

I tried to get values by this code

```
  $(".css-checkbox").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var searchIDs = $("input:checkbox").map(function(){
              //  return $(this).val();
            }).get(); // <----
            console.log(searchIDs);
        });
```

And it returns empty array .
Can somebody please help me ?

Link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gcLcn7bc/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
  $(".css-checkbox").click(function (event) {
      var searchIDs = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
          return $(this).val();
      }).get(); 
      alert(searchIDs);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="30" name="checkbox15" id="checkbox2" class="css-checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox2" class="css-label radGroup label_border css-checkbox_cl clr">test</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="23" name="checkbox15" id="checkbox3" class="css-checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox3" class="css-label radGroup label_border css-checkbox_cl clr">test2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="15" name="checkbox15" id="checkbox4" class="css-checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox4" class="css-label radGroup label_border css-checkbox_cl clr">test3</label>
```

Try to use `:checked` selector,

```
  $(".css-checkbox").click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var searchIDs = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
          return $(this).val();
      }).get(); // <----
      console.log(searchIDs);
  });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gcLcn7bc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".css-checkbox").click(function(event){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcLcn7bc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $('.css-checkbox').click(function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
      console.log(value);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $(".css-checkbox").change(function(event){
      var searchIDs = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
                    return $(this).val();
                }).get(); 
                console.log(searchIDs);
            });
```